# Wildcard SSL certificate subdomain mismatch with www - Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

Below is a snippet from my httpd.conf file. The problem I'm having is that when I access "https://www.subdomain2.domain.co.uk" I get a "certificate error" indicator in the URL bar in IE7:

```
"The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different 
website's address"
```

The strange thing is "https://www.domain.co.uk" and "https://subdomain1.domain.co.uk" work fine.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName *.domain.co.uk
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1.domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain1.domain.co.uk/$1 [P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain2.domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.subdomain2.domain.co.uk/$1 [P]
```

Comment: @cjc below is right. Look at using a redirect from www.subdomain2.domain.co.uk to subdomain.domain.co.uk or purchase another wildcard cert.

Comment: @KM01, the redirect won't work, since the SSL handshake (and the certificate warning) will happen before HTTP.

Comment: You're right @cjc. I meant redirect from **http**://www.subdomain... to **https**://subdomain...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcard certificates only work for one level of the name.  So, if your current cert works for subdomain2.domain.co.uk, it will not work for www.subdomain2.domain.co.uk.  You will need another wildcard in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. This is a certificate problem, nothing else. You may have a certificate that is valid *only* for www and subdomain1. **Only**. The solution is to buy a certificate with a wildcard (= more expensive). This way it will be valid for all the subdomains.

For more information about wildcard ssl certificates, see [here](http://help.godaddy.com/article/567) and [here](http://www.thawte.com/ssl/wildcard-ssl-certificates/index.html).